# Com+ Managed service starting slowly

Tags: c#, com+

I have a small 32 bit com+ service written in dotnet, that on some servers seems to start slowly 30+ seconds the first time it is run.  On others merely 4.  The servers this happens on are 64 bit, it has not been seen on 32 bit servers and not all 64 bit servers.

I am trying to figure out why, so Please - any pointers as to what to look at or suggestion would be most helpful while I still have some hair left.

Key Points:

The service runs as a NT Service under the Local Machine Account.  Changing it to a service under the user account does sometimes speed it back up, but not an option on Citrix servers.

The service uses Shared Property Group manager.

Dotnet Framework 3.5

The service reads and writes to %programdata%\servicename

uses config file based on DLL name Loaded from path of Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase Via an ExeConfigurationFileMap

It is not regstered in the GAC has various interop dependencies so does not work from it.